# Immutable.js - is it possible to insert element into list at arbitrary position?

Tags: immutable.js

How do I insert an element at arbitrary position of `Immutable.js` List?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are looking for the [`splice`method](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/set):

> Splice returns a new indexed Iterable by replacing a region of this Iterable with new values.
>
> `splice(index: number, removeNum: number, ...values: any[])`

Where you can specify the `index` and if you write `0` as `removeNum` it will just insert the values at the given position:

```
var list = Immutable.List([1,2,3,4]);
console.log(list.toJS()); //[1, 2, 3, 4]
var inserted = list.splice(2,0,100);
console.log(list.toJS()); //[1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(inserted.toJS()); //[1, 2, 100, 3, 4]
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oLcegfjj/).

Comment: Perhaps it is important to mention that immutability means that you create a new array from the expression rather than modify the existing one, and that this is a critical part of functional programming in general.

Comment: I imagine that anyone using a library called Immutable.js would already be familiar with that.

Answer (score 15):

It is worth pointing out that you can also use the [insert](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/insert) method which is in fact synonymous with `list.splice(index, 0, value)` but it feels more intuitive and improves readability greatly.

```
const myImmutableList = Immutable.fromJS(['foo', 'baz'])
const newList = myImmutableList.insert(1, 'bar')

console.log(newList.toJS()) //["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Comment: Does a prepend method exists, in order to avoid doing insert at index 0? To improve readability also ?

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, since using `insert()` does not require one to use `.toJS()` to convert the list to a regular array

Comment: @tommyalvarez there's an `unshift()` function to prepend a value to the list